# how to click under Telerik popup, where link is under <Tr>, using selenium web driver c#

Tags: selenium, telerik, webdriver

I am unable to click link under telerik popup, as the link is under

[image]

I tried with Switching windows but no help.

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("RadWindowWrapper_ctl00_rwCompanyNavV1");
```

even tried to click directly using `ID`

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("rptCompanies_ctl04_lnkEntityName")).Click();
```

Comment: Don't post a screen shot of code, post the code.

Comment: What is the error, you are getting??

Answer (score 0):

You don't show which error was there (which you should do), but I would suggest you check:

1) Is the ID static or dynamic? if it's dynamic you should try to use something else to locate the link

2) In the case the ID is static, try to wait for `visibilityOfElementLocated`